# R - How to pick a fix lambda in Glnment package

Tags: r

We try to compute the lasso estimate by using the Glmnet. Instead of using cv.glmnet, we want to to fix the lambda to 0.34 and then compute the coefficients. However, when we later check the value of Lambda R gives Lambda=NULL. Any clue how to fix the lambda?

```
# sample the data
q <- rnorm(n*p, mean=0, sd=1) #create the  matrix values from N(0,1)
x <- matrix(q, nrow=n, ncol=p)
e <- rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=1) # create error array
y <- x%*%beta1 + e # get the y values

#compute the coefficients LASSO
lasso <- glmnet(x,y)
lambda <- lasso$lambda.1se # selected lambda by cross-validation
beta.hat <- as.matrix(coef(lasso, s=0.34)) #get the estimate beta's
beta.hat <- beta.hat[2:(p+1),1] # delete intercept
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the lambda, use the option lambda in `glmnet::glmnet`:

```
glmnet(x=x, y=y, lambda=0.34)
```

Here is a reproducible example (I provided value for `n,p,beta1`) :

```
# sample the data
require(glmnet)
set.seed(1)
n = 100; p =10
q <- rnorm(n*p, mean=0, sd=1) #create the  matrix values from N(0,1)
x <- matrix(q, nrow=n, ncol=p)
e <- rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=1) # create error array
beta1 <- runif(10)
y <- x%*%beta1 + e # get the y values

#compute the coefficients LASSO
lasso <- glmnet(x,y, lambda = 0.34)
lasso$lambda #output 0.34
beta.hat <- as.matrix(coef(lasso)) #get the estimate beta's
beta.hat <- beta.hat[-1, 1] # remove intercept
```

In your example `lambda.1se` is `NULL` since you use `glmnet::glmnet` which does not cross-validate the lambda (instead of `glmnet::cv.glmnet`).